# rbenv local version is different than ruby -v

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I apologize if I leave out any needed information, I am terrible at debugging environment errors.

Problem: I need to change my ruby version to 1.9.3, it is currently 2.0.0p247

What I tried?

I used the commands:

```
rbenv local 1.9.3-p448
```

This switched my rbenv to 1.9.3-p448
When I do ruby -v it is still 2.0.0p247

My understanding of rbenv is that when I switch it locally my ruby version should also switch to the version rbenv is on. Unfortunately this is not the case.

I am in the process of trying to look at the PATH rbenv is tied to, this is an area I really  do not know much about.  I have been reading other posts related to my problem but so far I haven't been able to successfully change my ruby -v.

Comment: specify proper ruby version  in `Gemfile`, or in `.ruby-version` file. and just re enter to the project's folder

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use the version in .ruby-version.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: I can't change my ruby version to 1.9.3, when I run rbenv local 1.9.3-p448 it changes the rbenv to 1.9.3 but it doesn't change the ruby -v, it stasy at 2.0.0p247

Comment: can you `echo $PATH` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: @HelloWorld please, change it in `.ruby-version`, then reenter to folder `(cd ..;cd project)`, and try again: `ruby -v`

Answer (score 0):

So this was my problem.

I had a .bash_profile and a .bashrc

These settings for rbenv were in my .bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init)"
```

My PATH didn''t have the reference to shims as a result(and .rbenv/bin).

After tweaking my .bash_profile and inserting:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
source ~/.bashrc
```

I then added

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init)"
```

into my .bashrc

My PATH is now        `PATH=/Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/Users/me/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Prior to making these adjustments my PATH looked something like

'/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

Comment: It think the last line should be: eval "$(rbenv init -)" (Notice the minus-sign)